# Downloading URL using AWK for fixed fields

Tags: awk, data-download

I have a text file as follows

```
a   k   testis  adult   male    8 week  rRNA    https://www.encodeproject.org/files/ENCFF001JPX/@@download/ENCFF001JPX.fastq.gz
b   k   testis  adult   male    8 week  rRNA    https://www.encodeproject.org/files/ENCFF001JPZ/@@download/ENCFF001JPZ.fastq.gz
c   k   testis  adult   male    8 week  rRNA    https://www.encodeproject.org/files/ENCFF001JQB/@@download/ENCFF001JQB.fastq.gz
```

The file is tab delimited and has 8 columns with 8th column being the url link  I need to download the files one by one using wget and changing the name of the downloaded file with -O option in wget. The argument I want to give to the -O option is combination col1 and col2 separated by _ so that for first line I get the downloaded file as a_k.fastq.gz and so on. For example, the first line of the file above should give:

```
wget https://www.encodeproject.org/files/ENCFF001JPX/@@download/ENCFF001JPX.fastq.gz -O a_k.fastq.gz
```

Following the post from [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/410710/splitting-a-line-into-array-in-bash-with-tab-as-delimiter?noredirect=1#comment735962_410710) I realized looping through the file is slow and sometimes difficult. How can I download these files using wget with awk or cut as the tool for fixed fields

Comment: Can you post up an example wget command?

Comment: wget https://www.encodeproject.org/files/ENCFF001JPX/@@download/ENCFF001JPX.fastq.gz -O a_k.fastq.gz

Comment: how can I put it into code in the comment section??

Comment: edit the original post

Comment: @Llopis [we've decided](https://bioinformatics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/88/298) that basic things that bioinformaticians need to do in their daily work are on topic even when the issue could be expressed as a general text parsing question.

Comment: Ok, I misjudged and thought it was about downloading data.

Answer (score 5):

```
awk '{print "wget " $9 " -O " $1 "_" $2 ".fastq.gz"}' tmp
```

will give you

```
wget https://www.encodeproject.org/files/ENCFF001JPX/@@download/ENCFF001JPX.fastq.gz -O a_k.fastq.gz
wget https://www.encodeproject.org/files/ENCFF001JPZ/@@download/ENCFF001JPZ.fastq.gz -O b_k.fastq.gz
wget https://www.encodeproject.org/files/ENCFF001JQB/@@download/ENCFF001JQB.fastq.gz -O c_k.fastq.gz
```

If you add a `| bash` to the command it will then execute all the `wget` commands.

Comment: This works great. Can you tell what |bash is doing ??

Comment: @user3138373 the output of the awk command is a set of shell commands, essentially a mini script. By piping it to bash with `| bash` you're telling it to execute each input line as a command. So it will run the `wget` calls and download the sequences.

Answer (score 4):

A variation of [Bioathlete’s answer](/a/3072/2042) that doesn't suffer from escaping issues:

```sh
awk 'BEGIN{ FS="\t" } { printf("%s\t%s_%s.fastq.gz\n", $8, $1, $2) }' input |
while IFS=$'\t' read -r url filename; do
    wget -O "$filename" -- "$url"
done
```

Or entirely with shell parsing:

```sh
while IFS=$'\t' read -r c1 c2 c3 c4 c5 c6 c7 url; do
    wget -O "${c1}_${c2}.fastq.gz" -- "$url"
done < input
```

Or entirely without shell parsing but with GNU `xargs`:

```sh
awk 'BEGIN{ FS="\t" } { printf("%s_%s.fastq.gz\n%s\n", $1, $2, $8) }' input |
xargs -r -d '\n' -n 2 -- wget -O
```

… you could even run multiple `wget` instances in parallel from GNU `xargs` with the `-P` option, though you should set the `-q` option on `wget` to disable progress bars overwriting each other on the same terminal. Then again it would be better to use a real command-line download manager like Aria or Axel for that task.